# Monitoring Kubernetes Pod Disk IOPS: is there any relevant exporter?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have a bunch of statefulset applications notably Kafka Brokers, and Kafka Stream client application, including some DB, all deployed in Kubernetes. I would like to be able to build a grafana dashboard which would include the IOPS on the disk of the application above.

Is there a way to monitor the disk IOPS of a pod, and if not of the node on which the application is running. What kubernetes Prometheus exporters exist our there that could give me this information ?

Comment: Did you find any good solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can check cAdvisor metrics (in GKE included in kubelet by default). It will provide *container_fs* metrics, so you can calculate pod IOPS with:

```
max by (pod, device)(rate(container_fs_reads_total{container!=""}[5m]))
max by (pod, device)(rate(container_fs_writes_total{container!=""}[5m]))
```